# How to save data in SharedPreferences after closing the login menu?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to save my data where I get the data from JSON and I want to save it for login activity. In login activity I want it to check if the data exist so it no need to login anymore. So I using `SharedPreferences` to save the data but I don't know it saved or not because I can't track it if the app terminated. But it suddenly intent itself before I put some data on it.

This is my code where I get the data from JSON and save it to `sharedpreferences`.

```
String jsonData = response.body().string();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
            token = object.getString("access_token");
            Log.d("isi token", "" + token);
            if (response.code() == 200) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new userData().execute();
                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("token", token);
                        editor.commit();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, JudulActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
```

and this is my data where I retrieve the data from `sharedpreferences` and want to make the logic to login if the token null so it will not intent. but it intent before I call the JSON.

```
Log.d("token", "" + token2);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    token2 = sharedPreferences.getString("token", "");
    Log.d("token2", "" + token2);
    if (token2 == null) {
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                nameS = username.getText().toString();
                passS = password.getText().toString();

                if (nameS.isEmpty()) username.setError("Username belum diisi");
                else if (passS.isEmpty()) password.setError("Password belum diisi");
                else {
                    new login().execute();
                }
            }

        });
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, JudulActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The Log.d in the token is null but in token2 nothings happen, please help how to make it right.

Comment: beside saving, saving token in shared preferences is not secure. It is better to use some lib which makes it a lot harder to get token from device. For example https://github.com/adorsys/secure-storage-android

Comment: is to use that just like sharedpreferences?

Comment: Yes, it works really simillary. The only problem is it can cause a little lag when saving without using another thread and callbacks, but it is not huge problem I guess. And it is a lot more secure

Comment: i think it cant be save the String that really long

Comment: My tokens were saved without problem, no idea why your wouldn't be saved. Hard to tell

Comment: are you using `SecurePreferences.setValue("token", token);` to put the token and use `SecurePreferences.getStringValue("token", "");` to retrieve it?

Comment: yes, I use exactly it

Comment: i got this error `Caused by: de.adorsys.android.securestoragelibrary.SecureStorageException: Problem during Encryption
                             at de.adorsys.android.securestoragelibrary.SecurePreferences.setValue(Unknown Source)` when i setValue using that

Comment: No idea. Create issue on author's github then or look for some other secure way to keep token. 
https://github.com/adorsys/secure-storage-android/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
token2 = sharedPreferences.getString("token", "");
```

it will get default value `""` so it not be null for that you have to try this

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(token2)){
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Write to shared preferences**

To write to a shared preferences file, create a SharedPreferences.Editor by calling edit() on your SharedPreferences.

Pass the keys and values you want to write with methods such as `putInt()` and putString(). Then call `apply()` or `commit()` to save the changes. For example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

**Read from shared preferences**

To retrieve values from a shared preferences file, call methods such as `getInt()` and `getString()`, providing the key for the value you want, and optionally a default value to return if the key isn't present. For example:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.saved_high_score_default_key);
int highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), defaultValue);
```